# Get the list of data order by the way it was inserted before by C# MongoDB Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using C# Mongo DB Driver for database operation.

I want to get the list of records order by the way records are inserted. Because I believe MongoDB *by default sorts data on it's primary key* (e.g. `_Id`),

I want to get the *list of records by the order based on the way it was inserted.*  (I don't want to store DateTime data in table document).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right. If you don't provide a value of `_id` field on insertion, MongoDB will generate one. And those values will increase with time. So, if you sort by `_id` in ascending order, you'll get insertion order (accurate to the second, if I'm not mistaken).

For capped collections, there's a [special sorting order](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order) available: `$natural`. It is a guaranteed insertion order (but only for capped collections).

Comment: Does it possible that MongoDB will generate (by C# MongoDB Driver) a lower RowId than it's inserted record before? If MongoDB generates the lower RowId string for new record, then I cannot order the data on _Id !!

Comment: @nunu: that shouldn't happen. Have you encountered this situation?

Comment: You're right.. It's not happening that way... Awesome, Thanks!!

Comment: Yes.. I gone through that but it's for capped collection. We don't have capped collection for now!! Thanks for sharing..